# Maven issue:Regarding Testng

Tags: testing, maven

I have a module A which runs through pom.xml and accesses a testng.xml which in turn calls a specific class.This class displays a list of things for the user to choose from.
I am taking the user value through bufferRead.The bufferRead does not detect the value entered by the User.
ie
Enter the test u want to run
1.Test1
2.Test2
3.Test3
1

(control never goes to the next line)
There goes my pom.xml

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>`
```

This is my testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><suite allow-return-values="false" configfailurepolicy="skip" data-provider-thread-count="10" group-by-instances="false" junit="false" name="Suite" parallel="false" preserve-order="true" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false" thread-count="5">
<test allow-return-values="false" group-by-instances="false" junit="false" name="Test" preserve-order="true" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false">
    <classes>
    <class name="com.org.Console1"<methods>
    <include name="main" />
  </methods>
    </class>    
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
```

This is my java code that runs

```
System.out.println("Which tests do you want to run");
 String input = bufferRead.readLine();
```

Comment: This is the testng.xml                                  <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>

Comment: This is the testng.xml                                        <class name="org.com.mavenConsole">
    <methods>
        <include name="main" />
      </methods>
      </class>

Comment: This is the java code..System.out.println("Which tests do you want to run");                                                           String input = bufferRead.readLine();

Comment: You've not shared enough code - we cannot tell what happens after you read the input from the user. Please provide additional details (by editing the *question*, not by posting additional data in the comments).

Comment: Please also add your other examples to the question above. I tried to do this myself, but the edit was rejected for some reason.